# Why it runs successfully on my local (XAMPP) and giving error on server

Tags: php, server, model, xampp

The problem I am facing is

> Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in Setting_model.php on line 32

When I try to access a application on my server. Where as it runs or gives the expected output on localhost (XAMPP).

Earlier my server PHP version was 5.3.x and I was getting an error

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a
>   non-object in Setting_model.php on line 32

Then I have upgraded my PHP version to 5.6.38 on my server and the error becomes

> Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in Setting_model.php on line 32

After looking at a few post on SO and other website I am sure I can rectify the issue and make it work. as the line number 32 is

```
$result = $query->result_array();
```

I can make it like

```
$result = $query;
```

and this line will not give me error .. but the whole code of around more than 25k lines are written in this way. I am sure even If I try to make most of the changes I'll miss a few places which will in turns affect the production and it might crash at any point of time.

So now my question is.

Why it runs successfully on my local (XAMPP) and giving error on server?

or

What should I do to run `$query->result_array();` code on my server.

Comment: Have a look at this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028377/codeigniter-result-array-on-boolean-error-if-the-table-is-empty